# Provide ability to change "interested" to "not interested" on Careers

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature request.

I recently had a message on Careers, to which I prematurely hit "Interested." I then later wanted to change to "Not Interested" but am unable to do so.

> You've already given us your feedback for this job.

It seems that you should be able at any point to change from "Interested" to "Not Interested."

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the feedback!

The "interested" and "not interested" buttons are nothing more than convenient shortcuts equivalent to sending an actual message in which you state that you are interested or not interested. There's no functionality beyond that (e.g. after clicking "not interested," employers may still send you messages).

In the situation you describe, users would simply follow up with an actual message indicating they are no longer interested.